# Python: Caesar shift - inputting string that contains multiple "#'{]$ values

Tags: python

I created a caesar shift program in python, see below:

```
from string import maketrans

originalChar = (raw_input("Enter a letter: "))
numToInc = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
code = ""

for x in originalChar:
    newChar = (chr(ord(x) + numToInc))
    code = code + newChar

transtab = maketrans(chr(32+numToInc), " ")
print code.translate(transtab)
```

I have to shift the following code:

```
%%$@_$^__#)^)&!_+]!*@&^}@[@%]()%+$&[(_@%+%$*^@$^!+]!&_#)_*}{}}!}_]$[%}@[{_@#_^{*
@##&{#&{&)*%(]{{([*}@[@&]+!!*{)!}{%+{))])[!^})+)$]#{*+^((@^@}$[**$&^{$!@#$%)!@(&
+^!{%_$&@^!}$_${)$_#)!({@!)(^}!*^&!$%_&&}&_#&@{)]{+)%*{&*%*&@%$+]!*__(#!*){%&@++
!_)^$&&%#+)}!@!)&^}**#!_$([$!$}#*^}$+&#[{*{}{((#$]{[$[$$()_#}!@}^@_&%^*!){*^^_$^
```

As you can see, it contains comments.

How do I make that code into a string? The comments are stopping my python script from giving any output.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tripple quote it:

```
"""%%$@_$^__#)^)&!_+]!*@&^}@[@%]()%+$&[(_@%+%$*^@$^!+]!&_#)_*}{}}!}_]$[%}@[{_@#_^{*
@##&{#&{&)*%(]{{([*}@[@&]+!!*{)!}{%+{))])[!^})+)$]#{*+^((@^@}$[**$&^{$!@#$%)!@(&
+^!{%_$&@^!}$_${)$_#)!({@!)(^}!*^&!$%_&&}&_#&@{)]{+)%*{&*%*&@%$+]!*__(#!*){%&@++
!_)^$&&%#+)}!@!)&^}**#!_$([$!$}#*^}$+&#[{*{}{((#$]{[$[$$()_#}!@}^@_&%^*!){*^^_$^"""
```

Triple quoted strings can span multiple lines as well as have comments in them.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Can't believe I didn't think to try that. Multi-line string.  Thanks iCodez. Will accept as correct answer.

Comment: If you need to handle arbitrary input (not just the input sample shown), the triple-quote approach doesn't work in general.  Example, if the code contains sequences that are interpreted as Python escape sequences such as `\n` (newline), `\u0020` (unicode space) or many others, you will not get a verbatim, character-for-character version of the original code.  You need to use a leading `r` outside the triple-quotes.  See my answer for an example of this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Surround the input text between triple quotes: `"""your code"""`

Comment: If you need to handle arbitrary input (not just the input sample shown), the triple-quote approach doesn't work in general.  Example, if the code contains sequences that are interpreted as Python escape sequences such as `\n` (newline), `\u0020` (unicode space) or many others, you will not get a verbatim, character-for-character version of the original code.  You need to use a leading `r` outside the triple-quotes.  See my answer for an example of this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The triple-quote approach won't work if your source string contains Python escape characters.  For example, the sequence `\n` means newline, and is interpreted (correctly) as one character, not two.

If you want a general solution in which all the characters provided in your input are captured as-is and without escaping / interpretation, use the raw string approach via a leading `r` outside the quotes:

```
>>> s = '\n\n\n'
>>> print len(s)
3
```

vs.

```
>>> r = r'\n\n\n'
>>> print len(r)
6
```

No special cases to worry about.